# Shell code with curl command is throwing error malformed

Tags: shell

I have a curl command :

```
list_groups=$(curl -u GET "${name_host}/groups/listeridentifier")
echo "${list_groups}"
```

It return an error:

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

I tried by only Echo :

```
echo " result1 $(curl -u GET "${name_host}/groups/listeridentifier") result2"
```

always return the same error:

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
 result 1 result2
```

The parameter name_host is:

```
http://host_name:number_port
```

Knowing that it worked well when I execute it in API REST (HttpRequest) I change just the name of host and the number of port also in ssh. Only in my shell code.

Someone can tell me where's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `-u` then curl is going to be expecting a parameter for the user you want to act as.

```
curl --help
...
-u --user USER[:PASSWORD]  Server user and password
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question though but I faced the same issue. For me, the issue was due to extra '\r' char at the end of the url. Try removing that.
OR
If you are using shell script to run, like this test.sh, below command will remove the '\r' from url.
$tr -d '\r' < test.sh >  test1.sh
Now, running the test1.sh successfully execute the curl command.